# How to check if site is accessible to search bot

Tags: search, seo

Are there any tests that I can run to see if search bots can access my site?

Comment: Dunno who downvoted you, but I thought this was a good question as I myself just googled the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. spec: http://www.robotstxt.org/
2. Syntax check: http://www.searchenginepromotionhelp.com/m/robots-text-tester/robots-checker.php
3. accessibility check: http://phpweby.com/services/robots

<sub>*All of which are friends of google, so it seemed*</sub>